# UK visa AI kept saying "please now enter the longer card number found on the front of your debit or credit card"

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I was calling UK visa service VFS Global Bahrain (+44 20 3481 1736) to ask about my visa application progress. They asked for credit card information in order to charge for the call. However, when they asked me to enter credit card numbers, I could not get my card number through. It was always saying "please now enter the longer card number found on the front of your debit or credit card". I tried typing a wrong number and indeed they told me that the card number was invalid.

Comment: So, given your answer, it appears that the real question is "I didn't follow the instructions and it didn't work. What should I do?" and the answer is "Follow the instructions."

Comment: No. The real answer is: Don't follow the instructions that don't apply here.

Comment: Pressing hash wasn’t “an instruction that didn’t apply”: it wasn’t an instruction at all. The only instruction was to enter your card number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:
Unlike other calling services, their visa phone call does NOT accept # button after card number entry. You have to enter your card number without ending with a # and wait.

Comment: Did you mean to type "You have to enter your *card* number..."?

Comment: @Dr_Hope In the U.K. the AI will typically say ‘enter your card number followed by #’ if you are required to end your card number input with this symbol

Comment: @phoog Ooops. Good catch! already edited. Thanks

Comment: @Traveller It might be less ambiguous to say "followed by the hash key", given the occasional US tendency to call # a pound sign.

Comment: @origimbo It's more than an "occasional US tendency"; it's the common name of the sign in the US.  I suppose many people in the US would have no idea what "hash key" means.  But until you raised the issue, nobody here has made any assertions about the name of the symbol.

Comment: @Traveller in the US, one is frequently instructed to add that symbol, but it is often not required; it just bypasses a timer.  It's natural therefore to assume that one can (or should) add it even if not told to.

Comment: @phoog, In the US I've experienced number, pound and hash, although I'd got the impression hash-tagging had increased the occurrence of the latter. In the UK it's always 'hash' over the phone, for fairly obvious reasons.